# Create an alias from netbeans.exe

Tags: java, bash, netbeans

I'm trying to modify the default JDK on netbeans. IDE 10, but int the file netbeans.config when I change the path...well it doesn't find the jdk folder to point.

So at the end, the only way that I found to change JDK (from 1.8 (Default) to 11.0.2 (Default)) is doing this on the bash:

```
$ cd /path/to/netbeans/bin
$ ./netbeans --jdkhome /path/to/jdk/Home
```

So, doing this it works, and now I would like to create an alias with this following instruction to open easily Netbeans with JDK 11.0.2 as Default

Comment: alias netbeans_12='/path/to/netbeans/bin/netbeans --jdkhome /path/to/jdk/Home'

Comment: The file to edit should be `netbeans.conf` not `netbeans.config`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
alias nbjdk11="cd /path/to/netbeans/bin && ./netbeans --jdkhome /path/to/jdk/Home"
```